# javascript response is null

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am doing a response to php script.

```
<script >
function showHint(str) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "gethint.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
} </script>
```

And after i call showHint(str), i do:

```
var result = document.getElementById("result");
```

And it's always null. But this works fine and gives a right text:

```
<p><span id = "result"></span></p>
```

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: If `document.getElementById("result")` is returning `null`, that means that the element isn't available. Are you running your script *after* you've loaded in the rest of your HTML (a.k.a at the bottom of the `body`)?

Comment: Yes, i'm running script in the bottom of the body.

Comment: It sounds like the AJAX request hasn't finished before `var result = document.getElementById("result");` runs.  You probably want to look into a callback function:  http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp

Comment: Could you create an example using the integrated snippet functionality or [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)? As it's written, that will only be null if the element doesn't exist. If you mean the `innerHTML` is empty then refer to @AdamKonieska

Comment: I'm already working on it @MikeC, its tough without a working AJAX endpoint to create a proof of concept.

Comment: @AdamKonieska No, I was saying that OP needs to create an example but that you're probably right.

Comment: Are you using Google Chrome? Press f12 to see errors, and which lines they are occurring. Clicking the error link will bring you to the line with the error. Then post the error and the line of code that gives you the error.

Comment: Or if you are coding on your website, post the link to the website with the error.

Comment: @frosty You should *never* link to a website exhibiting the error. Because as soon as they fix it, this question becomes useless to future visitors.

Comment: You can look at the full html fragment here: https://jsfiddle.net/rjghqgax/.

Comment: @hgfdd It's broken because you put all of the code in the JS section *and* it doesn't contain any elements with an ID of "result".

Comment: @MikeC Well, this is just so WE know what OP is doing wrong. After that, he can just delete the link, and edit the error into his post.

Comment: @MikeC And if it's not hard for you, can you tell me, what i need to do to improve it?

Comment: @hgfdd A lot. First off, [you could run your HTML through a validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) because a lot of your HTML isn't valid, such as using 2 `<title>`s and using an `<h1>` in the head. Next, make sure you actually have a `<span id="result"></span>` in your HTML because right now you don't.

Comment: @MikeC If i have `<span id="result"></span>` in my code. It is not NULL, but have empty `innerHTML`. I still don't have the value from php script. I have done this before and it's not the way.

Comment: @hgfdd Look at the JSFiddle you posted. There is no "span" element in it. If you want the innerHTML *after* the AJAX request, you have to handle it in the callback where you assign the "innerHTML".